# mssql_query() hangs up when I changed from PHP 5.2.17 to 5.6.2

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, freebsd

I have  a php script which must get data from standalone MS SQL Sever 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)  table and make some manipulation on them. The table contains about 6000 rows. Initially that script was running  on FreeBSD 8.0,  PHP 5.2.17, FreeTDS 0.91.103. Execution time was 1.06 sec.
When I moved my script on FreeBSD 10.0 with PHP 5.6.2 and tryed to start it with CLI it hanged up without any error reports. When I insert in my query "SELECT TOP 5.....", script begins to execute and Execution time is 0.2 sec. This is fragment of my script:

```
<?php    
....    
$start =  microtime(true);  
$q = 'SELECT  svid, date_svid, name_derj, addr_derj, email_derj, addr_derj,     vidwork, filial, phone_derj from dbo.jsvid';  
$res = mssql_query($q) or die ('Can\'t execute query'. mssql_get_last_message());  
echo 'Num rows =',mssql_num_rows($res), "\n","</br>";  
echo 'Time = '.(microtime(true) - $start);  
......
```

This is output:

```
info# php -f jsvid_import.php  
Linking to SRV3 SQLEXPNET  
Linked!  
Num rows =6129  
Time = 1.06680607796  
info#
```

Please, give me any idea?

Comment: 1 Second on only 6000 rows? That's ages

Comment: MS SQL  server and Free BSD server are separeted by firewall.

Comment: The number one lesson to learn here is that you're asking for trouble by not upgrading for ages and then doing one big upgrade that upgrades multiple things at once and jumps several versions. There are so many changes between these systems that it's difficult to pin down the cause of the problem here. My suggestion is to try doing a step-by-step upgrade to see at what point things go wrong. You need to pin down the problem. My guess is that it'll be something in the server config; maybe DNS or SELinux or firewall settings, but without narrowing it down that is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I installed Free BSD 11.0-RELEASE-p1 and PHP 5.6.27 on my server, and myscript began to work with appropriate speed. 
Thank everybody for discussion.